# How to convert mySQL Query to Laravel 5.4 Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Please someone should help me convert this SQL Query to Laravel 5.4 Query Builder syntax. I have searched for solutions and found some but not exactly as I wanted.

I have 3 tables:

Feeds:
   - feed_id
   - user_id
   - feed_title

Users:
   - id
   - username

Commments:
   - comment_id
   - feed_id
   - text
   - user_id

On my view returned, I want to see the feed title, user's user name, and a count of all comments to each feed. Like what you see on facebook: displaying the amount of comments on each post displayed. Please I really need this to be done:

This is the SQL code I tried in MySQL Database, it kinda works there but returns an error when I try to implement the same in Laravel

```
select *, count(comments.comment_id) as comment_count 
from `feeds` 
inner join `users` on 
`feeds`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
inner join `comments` on 
`feeds`.`feed_id` = `comments`.`comment_feed_id` 
group by `comments`.`comment_feed_id`
```

Comment: Can you post your models relations?

Comment: I just want to use SQL to achieve this... but talking about relationships; user_id in feeds is a foreign key which is a primary key (id) in users. and feed_id is a primary key in feeds and a foreign key in comments table as (feed_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB::table('feeds')
    ->selectRaw('*, count(comments.comment_id) as comment_count')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'feeds.user_id')
    ->join('comments', 'feeds.id', '=', 'comments.comment_feed_id')
    ->groupBy('comments.comment_feed_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: it returns this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'behiind.feeds.feed_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select *, count(comments.comment_id) as comment_count from `feeds` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `feeds`.`user_id` inner join `comments` on `feeds`.`feed_id` = `comments`.`comment_feed_id` group by `comments`.`comment_feed_id`)

Comment: I got it, there is no feeds.feed_id.. See the updated query above

Comment: Please this is the working SQL, Please help convert to Laravel Query Builder. `select feeds.feed_category, feeds.title, users.username, feeds.feed_created_at, feeds.feed_views, count(comments.comment_id) as comment_count 
from `comments` 
right join `feeds` 
on `feeds`.`feed_id` = `comments`.`comment_feed_id` 
left join `users` 
on `users`.`id` = `feeds`.`user_id` 
group by `feeds`.`feed_id``

Comment: Let's talk in the chat, I'll help you. But why did you remove the acceptance?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, assuming the name of your model is "Feed":

```
Feed::selectRaw('feeds.*, count(comments.comment_id) as comment_count')
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'feeds.user_id')
->join('comments', 'feeds.feed_id', '=', 'comments.comment_feed_id')
->groupBy('comments.comment_feed_id')->get();
```

Comment: thanks, but it returns an error that says: "Class Feed not found"... do you know what is causing it?

Comment: I fixed the error it printed but now, it returns no values, the page is blank with no details

Comment: I forgot to put ->get() on the end! Should work now.