# Converting mysql queries to laravel syntax

Tags: mysql, laravel

I don't know how to convert subquery to laravel query.
How I can convert mysql query to laravel query? 
this is the query

```
select vd_id, subCount
from   (select vd_id, count(vd_id) subCount 
        from sell_data
        group by vd_id) sub
        where subCount = (select count(vd_id) maxCount
                          from sell_data
                          group by vd_id 
                          order by maxCount desc limit 1) 
           or subCount = (select count(vd_id) minCount
                          from sell_data
                          group by vd_id 
                          order by minCount asc limit 1) ;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927663/how-to-convert-mysql-query-to-laravel-5-4-query-builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$from = DB::table('sell_data')->select('vd_id')->selectRaw('count(vd_id) subCount')
    ->groupBy('vd_id');
$results = DB::query()
    ->select('vd_id', 'subCount')
    ->fromSub($from, 'sub')
    ->where('subCount', function($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('count(vd_id) maxCount')
            ->from('sell_data')
            ->groupBy('vd_id')
            ->orderByDesc('maxCount')
            ->limit(1);
    })
    ->orWhere('subCount', function($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('count(vd_id) minCount')
            ->from('sell_data')
            ->groupBy('vd_id')
            ->orderBy('minCount')
            ->limit(1);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response.